# Elpy to allow pyenv to work on a project basis

Tags: emacs, pyenv, elpy

I've used Emacs for all my coding projects so far. Soon I will start some python projects for the first time and would love to stick to Emacs for these as well.

I was looking into elpy which seems to provide already alot of desired functionality. The part I was not able to figure out completely is the following. I like to define virtual environments and python version to be used on a project basis. Let's say I start a project A, then I would use [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) or [pyenv-virtualenvwrapper](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper) to set it up

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.4.2 my-virtual-env-3.4.2
```

by doing this I've linked the python version 3.4.2 to that specific virtualenv / project. I have two questions regarding this in combination with elpy.

**Question: This is a rather basic one. All the above can be achieved via the terminal. What is the advantage to emacs to support this? The workflow for me would be: Create project with associated virtualenv and python version. Activate virtualenv and start coding in emacs. If I need to install a package I will run pip in the terminal to ensure virtualenv is captured properly. There must be a reason why it's beneficial to support this in emacs. With my lack of knowledge I just don't see it :)**

As pointed out there is for sure a good reason why we want emacs / elpy to support this.  My second question would then be

**Question: How can I achieve this in emacs? Lokks like this [blog](https://smythp.com/emacs/python/2016/04/27/pyenv-elpy.html) has a solution. I was wondeirng if someone already tried this setup if it is a neat solution with makes sense conceptually. **

Answer (score 1):

Well I strongly guess the goal is to use more features than just syntax highlighting: flycheck/flake8/linting, refactoring, elpy's test runner to use the right python version, install a pip package directly from emacs, stuff like this. You can carry on doing this in the terminal, but once you want an emacs feature, you'll need to set it up.

I found two modes to do that (see [wikemacs python page](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Python#Python_versions_.28pyenv.29) and doubled-checked [on melpa](https://melpa.org/#/)): [pyenv-mode](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) (in melpa) and `pyenv-mode-auto` (change the version when there is a .python-version file).

Comment: neither of which result in elpy-config knowing a venv is in use unfortunately.